# phpunit testing expectedException not working

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

I am trying to test my class for InvalidArgumentException but I get

> Tests\BarTest::should_receive_parameter Missing argument 1 for
>   Itdc\Foo\Bar::__construct(), called in
>   /mypath/foo/tests/BarTest.php on line 10 and
>   defined

This is the test (BarTest.php) file I use:

```
<?php namespace Tests;
use Itdc\Foo\Bar;
class BarTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /** @test */
    public function should_receive_parameter() {
        $this->setExpectedException('Exception');
        $id = new Bar;
    }
}
```

This is Bar class:

```
<?php namespace Itdc\Foo;
class Bar {
    public function __construct($a) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I have tried to puth setExpectedException in comment section, also tried to use InvalidArgumentException, but no luck.

Any suggetions what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you catch it directly you can var_dump() the exception.

```
/** @test */
public function shouldThrowException() {
  try {
    new Foo();
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
class PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning#19 (9) {
  ...
```

So here the source does not trigger an exception but an error, PHPUnit converts the error into a specific exception. But it does not include it in the assertions.

Try using the specific exception name:

```
/** @test */
public function shouldThrowException() {
  $this->setExpectedException('PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning');
  new Foo();
}
```

Comment: If you are like me and stumble across this post, updated phpunit has `$this->expectException(\Exception::class);
        $this->expectExceptionCode('the_expected_code');
        $this->expectExceptionMessage('Wrong exception');
` Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296581/how-to-use-expectexception-in-phpunit