# How to use expectException in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, testing, exception, phpunit

I'm trying to test my Exception, or any other exception in PHP Unit.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);


namespace Tests\Exception;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class DrinkIsInvalidExceptionTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testIsExceptionThrown(): void
    {
        $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
        try {
            throw new \Exception('Wrong exception');
        } catch(\Exception $exception) {
            echo $exception->getCode();
        }

    }

}
```

Still fails:

```
Failed asserting that exception of type "Exception" is thrown.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Came looking for a solution to this issue as well.  I haven't found any great documentation on this.  If I try the solution from Pablo (which looks valid) I still get an exception thrown.   If I put the expectException inside of the catch of a try-catch, the exception is caught, but it still outputs an error message during my test run.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that the exception is never thrown because you are catching it in the catch block.
The correct code to test your exception would be this:

```
class DrinkIsInvalidExceptionTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testIsExceptionThrown(): void
    {
        $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
        $this->expectExceptionCode('the_expected_code');
        $this->expectExceptionMessage('Wrong exception');

        // Here the method that throws the exception
        throw new \Exception('Wrong exception');
    }
}
```